# How do i add drop down field for credentials in the plugin im devloping

Tags: java, jenkins-plugins, credentials, jelly

I am some what new to extending Jenkins and was wondering how would i generate the code for adding a credentials drop down like the one in this picture. [image]
<sub>(source: [jenkins.io](https://wiki.jenkins.io/download/attachments/58917601/image2018-9-20_22-0-7.png))</sub>

I have looked at some examples and noted they used this jelly code

```
<f:entry title="${%Credentials}" field="credentialsId">
  <c:select/>
</f:entry>
```

But when i implement this my Credentials line in the build job settings dose not contain the drop down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note figured it out. Posting answer for others benefit. In order to dynamically fill the list you must create a doFillCredentialsIdItems like the method bellow along with adding a import to the credentials plugin.

```
public ListBoxModel doFillCredentialsIdItems(@AncestorInPath Item item, @QueryParameter String credentialsId) {
        StandardListBoxModel result = new StandardListBoxModel();
                        return result
                .includeEmptyValue()
                .includeAs(ACL.SYSTEM, Jenkins.get(),
                 UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl.class)
                .includeCurrentValue(credentialsId);
        }
```